# INSERT or UPDATE the values from a table A into the columns of table B based on table A's value in its row?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, eav

I have a table which contains attribute names with there values but each row is a attribute with its value,

| ItemId | ItemAttributeName | ItemAtributeValue |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 405 | Application | High AmpacityConnections |
| 405 | Color | Yellow |
| 405 | Environmental Conditions | Watertight |
| 405 | Material | Composite |
| 406 | Application | High AmpacityConnections |
| 406 | Color | Blue |
| 406 | Material | Brass |

so I created another table with all possible Attribute names to flatten it out so that each row will contain all values for each item.

| ItemId | Application | Color | Environmental Conditions | Material |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 405 | High Ampacity Connections | Yellow | Watertight | Composite |
| 406 | High Ampacity Connections | Blue |  | Wood |

How is it possible to take the first table and insert the data for each given itemId into the above table under corresponding columns?

I also need to consider that there is over a hundred different attribute names and not all items will have each attribute or value. I'm not really sure what direction I should go with this problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select itemid, 
       MAX(case 
              when itemattributename ='Application' then itemattributevalue 
              ELSE NULL END),
       MAX(case 
              when itemattributename ='Color' then itemattributevalue 
              ELSE NULL END)Color,
       ISNULL(MAX(case 
              when itemattributename ='Environmental Conditions' then 
                   itemattributevalue 
              ELSE NULL END),'')[Environmental Conditions],
       MAX(case 
              when itemattributename ='Material' then itemattributevalue 
             ELSE  NULL  END)Material
  from item
 group by itemid
```

The above solution works only if you have a definite number of attributes, if there in N number of attributes you should use [dynamic pivot](https://www.sqlshack.com/dynamic-pivot-tables-in-sql-server/) for this

Answer (score 2):

To complement the answer already provided by [Biju jose](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/295379), here is one way to do it with dynamic SQL.  If you add new rows to the `dbo.eav` table in my example, they automatically translate into new columns in the output.

```
USE tempdb;
GO

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS dbo.eav;
GO

CREATE TABLE dbo.eav
(
      [ItemId]              int             NOT NULL
    , [ItemAttributeName]   varchar(50)     NOT NULL
    , [ItemAttributeValue]  varchar(50)     NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO dbo.eav ([ItemId], [ItemAttributeName], [ItemAttributeValue])
VALUES
      (405, 'Application', 'High Ampacity Connections')
    , (405, 'Color', 'Yellow')
    , (405, 'Environmental Conditions', 'Watertight')
    , (405, 'Material', 'Composite')
    , (406, 'Application', 'High Ampacity Connections')
    , (406, 'Color', 'Blue')
    , (406, 'Material', 'Brass')
    , (407, 'Size', 'Small')
    , (407, 'Application', 'Stapler');

DECLARE @dynamic_sql nvarchar(max) = N'SELECT src.ItemId, ';

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #names;

SELECT e.ItemAttributeName
INTO #names
FROM dbo.eav e
GROUP BY e.ItemAttributeName
ORDER BY e.ItemAttributeName;

SET @dynamic_sql = @dynamic_sql + (
    SELECT STRING_AGG(QUOTENAME(e.ItemAttributeName) + N' = MAX(' + QUOTENAME(e.ItemAttributeName) + N')', N', ')
    FROM #names e
    );

SET @dynamic_sql = @dynamic_sql + N' FROM src GROUP BY src.[ItemId] ORDER BY src.[ItemId];'

SET @dynamic_sql = (
    SELECT N'
;WITH src AS 
(
    SELECT e.ItemId
        , ' + STRING_AGG(QUOTENAME(e.ItemAttributeName) + N' = CASE WHEN e.ItemAttributeName = ''' + e.ItemAttributeName + N''' THEN e.ItemAttributeValue ELSE NULL END', CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) + N'        , ')
    FROM #names e 
    ) 
    + '
    FROM dbo.eav e
)
' 
    + @dynamic_sql + N'

';

PRINT @dynamic_sql;
EXEC sys.sp_executesql @dynamic_sql;
```

Output from the above looks like:

| ItemId | Application | Color | Environmental Conditions | Material | Size |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 405 | High Ampacity Connections | Yellow | Watertight | Composite | NULL |
| 406 | High Ampacity Connections | Blue | NULL | Brass | NULL |
| 407 | Stapler | NULL | NULL | NULL | Small |

As you can see, my output includes ItemId 407, with an attribute of Size "Small".

Of course, as the unique number of `ItemAttributeName` values goes up, the wider the output becomes.  It seems unlikely that you'd really want to do that.  More likely would be to select a specific ItemId and only show the applicable columns.

The below example builds on the above code to show how you could dynamically select a specific `ItemId` (in this case 407), to show only the relevant columns:

```
USE tempdb;
GO

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS dbo.eav;
GO

CREATE TABLE dbo.eav
(
      [ItemId]              int             NOT NULL
    , [ItemAttributeName]   varchar(50)     NOT NULL
    , [ItemAttributeValue]  varchar(50)     NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO dbo.eav ([ItemId], [ItemAttributeName], [ItemAttributeValue])
VALUES
      (405, 'Application', 'High Ampacity Connections')
    , (405, 'Color', 'Yellow')
    , (405, 'Environmental Conditions', 'Watertight')
    , (405, 'Material', 'Composite')
    , (406, 'Application', 'High Ampacity Connections')
    , (406, 'Color', 'Blue')
    , (406, 'Material', 'Brass')
    , (407, 'Size', 'Small')
    , (407, 'Application', 'Stapler');


DECLARE @ItemIdFilter int = 407;
DECLARE @dynamic_sql nvarchar(max) = N'SELECT src.ItemId, ';

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #names;

SELECT e.ItemAttributeName
INTO #names
FROM dbo.eav e
WHERE e.ItemId = @ItemIdFilter
GROUP BY e.ItemAttributeName
ORDER BY e.ItemAttributeName;

SET @dynamic_sql = @dynamic_sql + (
    SELECT STRING_AGG(QUOTENAME(e.ItemAttributeName) + N' = MAX(' + QUOTENAME(e.ItemAttributeName) + N')', N', ')
    FROM #names e
    );

SET @dynamic_sql = @dynamic_sql + N' FROM src GROUP BY src.[ItemId] ORDER BY src.[ItemId];'

SET @dynamic_sql = (
    SELECT N'
;WITH src AS 
(
    SELECT e.ItemId
        , ' + STRING_AGG(QUOTENAME(e.ItemAttributeName) + N' = CASE WHEN e.ItemAttributeName = ''' + e.ItemAttributeName + N''' THEN e.ItemAttributeValue ELSE NULL END', CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) + N'        , ')
    FROM #names e 
    ) 
    + '
    FROM dbo.eav e
    WHERE e.ItemId = ' + CONVERT(nvarchar(20), @ItemIdFilter) + N'
)
' 
    + @dynamic_sql + N'

';

PRINT @dynamic_sql;
EXEC sys.sp_executesql @dynamic_sql;
```

The output from that looks like:

| ItemId | Application | Size |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 407 | Stapler | Small |

The dynamically generated T-SQL for the above output looks like:

```
;WITH src AS 
(
    SELECT e.ItemId
        , [Application] = CASE WHEN e.ItemAttributeName = 'Application' THEN e.ItemAttributeValue ELSE NULL END
        , [Size] = CASE WHEN e.ItemAttributeName = 'Size' THEN e.ItemAttributeValue ELSE NULL END
    FROM dbo.eav e
    WHERE e.ItemId = 407
)
SELECT src.ItemId, [Application] = MAX([Application]), [Size] = MAX([Size]) FROM src GROUP BY src.[ItemId] ORDER BY src.[ItemId];
```